# Django - import excel to database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model abd a excel table that represents a data that shluld be imported to the database.
How should I do that ?

Django 1.7

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this utility? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-import-export/?